# Python - Returning number of elements in array above a curved function

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, indexing

I'm trying to extract the number of values above the dashed, dotted-dashed, and dotted curves in my plot.

[image]

I can always eyeball the number of points that exceed the extent of these curves, but I do not want to risk any errors in this method.

First off, these curves are defined by a mass variable and a distance variable I call in my code `Escape_Velocity`. It is part of a class profile I have made.

```
import numpy as np
import NFW_Profile as NFW

h0 = 0.704
NFWc12 = NFW.Profile(c=12.5, z=0.0, h=h0)
nfwEsc = NFWc12.Escape_Velocity(Mass, Radius)
```

On my plot, the curves are based on this function, where I pick an arbitrary `Mass` value and `Radius` is fed a `np.linspace` value.

The values on my plot are from my analysis from data sets, where we can call
`RadVel` to be the y-axis values "Radial Velocity" and `Dist` to be the x-axis values "Galactocentric Distance".

The key part is that both of these arrays of elements are of the same dimension and that they can be indexed with one another. For example the 20th indexed value `RadVel` corresponds to the 20th indexed value of `Dist`.

---

So my plan from is to

1. Pick an arbitrary value of `Mass`
2. Take an element from `Dist`
3. Feed that value to `Escape_Velocity`
4. If the `RadVel` value, corresponding to the element fed to `Escape_Velocity`, is greater than the `Escape_Velocity` value, it counts.
5. If the `Escape_Velocity` is greater than the corresponding `RadVel` value, it does not count.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import NFW_Profile as NFW

   h0 = 0.704
   NFWc12 = NFW.Profile(c=12.5, z=0.0, h=h0)


   def UnboundSubhalos(mass, Dist):
       Vesc = NFWc12.Escape_Velocity(mass, Dist)

       PosValues = [i for i in RadVel if i => Vesc.all()]
       NegValues = [i for i in RadVel if i <= -Vesc.all()]

       return  len(PosValues) + len(NegValues)
   ```

Comment: So what is the question ? The only suggestion I have is in your `UnboundSubhalos` function you could do `return np.count_nonzero(np.abs(i) >= Vesc.all())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I got this, you want to find the number of red dots that are outside the region defined by a non-linear function you call `Escape_Velocity` and the red dots have x-positions and y-positions that are stored in the arrays `Dist` and `RedVal`, respectively, ordered so that a red dot has a position (x,y)=`(Dist[n], RedVel[n])`. Also, it looks like (and your definition of `UnboundSubhalos` suggests it) the dotted lines defined by `Escape_Velocity` are symmetric around `RedVel = 0`, i.e. you actually want to find the number of red dots with an absolute value of `RedVel` larger than `Escape_Velocity`.

In this case you can simply do the following: Assuming `Escape_Velocity` is a function you can pass an array to, you find the `Escape_Velocity` for every element of your array `Dist` and store it in the array `esc_vel = Escape_Velocity(Mass, Dist)`. Else you will have to calculate these values with a loop over the elements of `Dist`. From your code I can assume that `Escape_Velocity` gives a positive value, i.e. the dotted line at positive `RedVal` values. Then the array `outside_dots = np.abs(RedVel) >= esc_vel` contains `True` for every dot outside the region enclosed by the dotted curves and `False` for every dot inside. Then `np.sum(outside_dots)` gives you the desired number of dots outside.

The following code works like described:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

number_dots = 100
x = np.random.random(number_dots)  # random numbers in the range [0, 1]
y = (np.random.random(number_dots) - 0.5) * 2  # random numbers in the range [-1, 1]

curved_function = lambda z: 1 - np.sqrt(z)/3

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

def count_dots_outside(x, y):
        outside_dots = np.abs(y) > curved_function(x)
        return np.sum(outside_dots)

plt.title('Number of dots outside the curved function: '+str(count_dots_outside(x,y)))
xx = np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(xx, curved_function(xx), 'black', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(xx, -curved_function(xx), 'black', linestyle='dashed')
plt.show()
```